# Duplication of concerns javax.validation.constraints and javax.persistence.Column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, jpa

I would like to do some Bean validation of my entities so I can appropriately map the errors to send back to the client.

I understand that the **javax.validation.constraints** annotations are used to achieve this. 
My issue is that for my schema generation I need to use the **javax.persistence.Column** annotation, to describe rules for the persistence layer. This seems like I am duplicating my logic a little bit.

```
    @Size( max= Entities.SCHEMA_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Description", length = Entities.SCHEMA_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH)
    private String description;
```

As you can see I have to specify that the column is 'Not Nullable for both validation purposes and schema generation purposes (same for column length). This seems redundant. Surely there is a way to kill two birds with one stone in this case, as it seems like it would be pretty common, if not standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately although validation and schema generation may overlap at times (column length and nullability, for example) there's no interaction between them so you have to declare both concerns separately (and repeat yourself).

Comment: Hmm I was afraid this might be the case. Thanks.

**JPA** could really take a leaf (or two) out of **EnitityFramework's** book

Comment: @twomarktwo - youre welcome to try and suggest this as an optional hibernate feature in their jira - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa . judging by other issues (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HVAL-46) they might be receptive to the idea.

Comment: even better - i did it for you - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-484 . please vote for it :-)

Comment: Haha cheers mate, I was half way through submitting one. Have voted that up :)